# How do you use variables and expressions in a string template?

Tags: eval, template

I am trying to use a custom replacer function in `s-format` to enable a string template with this behavior:

```
(defun transform (x)
  (* 6 x))

(let ((a 5))
  (s-format "${(transform a)}" 'replacer '(())))
```

Ideally, this would resolve to a string of "30". I want this syntax because it is simpler to me than making a-lists with keys and values.

If I have `lexical-binding` set to nil that is what happens. But if `lexical-binding` is set to t, I get an error that the `Symbol’s value as variable is void: a`.

This is no doubt because I am (mis)-using `eval` (and maybe using other bad logic) in the replacer function:

```
(defun replacer (key data)
  (cond
   ;; sexp
   ((string-prefix-p "(" key)
    (eval (read key)))

   ;; bound variable
   ((and (boundp (intern-soft key))
     (symbol-value (intern-soft key))) 
    (symbol-value (intern-soft key)))

   ;; extract from data
   (t
    (or (cdr (assoc key data)) ""))))
```

The idea in this function is to see the key is an sexp starting with a (, and then read and eval it.That works in a dynamically bound env, but not in a lexically bound one. So, two questions I guess, first, is the string-prefix-p the best way to identify an sexp that could be evaluated? and second given that sexp, how do I reliably evaluate it in the environment it came from? Maybe third, is there some other tried and true way to achieve this goal, or should I just use the very verbose 'aget replacer and stick to a simpler template?

Comment: Unless there's a way to get access to the lexical environment above the current context, I don't think this is possible. The idea here can be implemented with macros, but I believe s-format as a function doesn't provide the ability to implement this. I'd love to be wrong though.

Comment: You’ve got something like four different questions in there; you should stick to just one question at a time.

Comment: I am not sure what is the goal here; or why you could not just use: `(let ((a 5)) (format "%d" (transform a)))` (you could surround that `(transfrom a)` with a replacer and/or replace `%d` with `%s` if necessary). Could you clear that up? B.t.w. a `sexp` does not have to start with a `(` (see e.g. [Parsing Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parsing-Expressions.html)).

Comment: Hey John, returning to this to share an example of how this type of behavior can be built using macros instead of functions.

It's not perfect, but this code does what you're trying to do with `s-format` but with a macro.

https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/592618ee665b18205676949f0b3766fa

Comment: And an older one that's better and worse in different ways: https://gist.github.com/jordonbiondo/c4e22b4289be130bc59b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(The intention of this response to engage.)

`eval` always happen within an `environment`.   **It is the environment that supplies values to the variables.**

In your example, the `eval` happens in dynamic environment, and the lisp evaluator, when it looks up in its `environment`, it  is not unable to find the value of a `variable`.

**So, the trick is to find out the `environment`  the `evaluator` is consulting, and to *insert* the *variable* and its *value* in that environment.**

In your case, a simple

```
M-: (setq a 5) RET
```

will do the job admirably.

**(Figure out where the `environment` in to which above `setq` puts the `value` and `variable`.)**

---

**Slightly an elaborate response**

eval is a built-in function in `C source code`.

```lisp
(eval FORM &optional LEXICAL)
```

Evaluate FORM and return its value.
If LEXICAL is `t`, evaluate using lexical binding by default.
This is the recommended value.

If absent or `nil`, use dynamic scoping only.

**LEXICAL can also represent an actual lexical environment; see the Info node `(elisp)Eval` for details.**

---

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Eval")
```

https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Eval

-- `Function: eval form &optional lexical`

This is the basic function for evaluating an expression.  **It evaluates FORM in the current environment, and returns the result.**  The type of the FORM object determines how it is evaluated.

**Note Forms::**.

The argument LEXICAL specifies the scoping rule for local variables(*note Variable Scoping::).

- If it is omitted or `nil`, that means to evaluate FORM using the default dynamic scoping rule.
- If it is`t`, that means to use the lexical scoping rule.  **The value of LEXICAL can also be *a non-empty alist* specifying a particular “lexical environment” for lexical bindings**; however, this feature is only useful for specialized purposes, such as in Emacs Lisp  debuggers.  *Note Lexical Binding::.

Since `eval` is a function, the argument expression that appears in a call to `eval` is evaluated twice: once as preparation before  `eval` is called, and again by the `eval` function itself.

---

```lisp
(info "(elisp) Lexical Binding")
```

https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Lexical Binding

Internally, **the lexical environment is an alist of symbol-value
pairs, with the final element in the alist being the symbol `t` rather
than a cons cell.  Such an alist can be passed as the second argument to the `eval` function, in order to specify a lexical environment in which to evaluate a form.**  *Note Eval::.  Most Emacs Lisp programs, however, should not interact directly with lexical environments in this way; only specialized programs like debuggers.)

---

Try the `setq` or try passing an explicit `environment` to  `eval`.

```lisp
(defvar kitchin-env
  '((a . 20)
    (b . 10)
    t))

(defun transform (x)
  (* 6 x))

(defun replacer (key env)
  (cond
   ;; sexp
   ((string-prefix-p "(" key)
    (eval (read key) env))

   ;; bound variable
   ((and (boundp (intern-soft key))
     (symbol-value (intern-soft key))) 
    (symbol-value (intern-soft key)))

   ;; extract from data
   (t
    (or (cdr (assoc key env)) ""))))

(s-format "${(transform a)}" 'replacer kitchin-env)
```

**When you do `symbol-value` what `envionment` is consulted for the `variable`'s `value`?**

(By now you should have understood that there could be multiple environments, and you can set them up "as you go".

And when you are in a `home` environment, and say **"Wait for `x` minutes!"**
you *really* mean **"Wait for `10x` or `20x` minutes"**

... and when you are in a `office` environment, and say **"Wait for `x` minutes!"** *(presumably to your boss)*, you really mean **"Wait for *less than* `x` minutes"** actually.  So, `context` / `environment` of computation really matters.

Comment: You can NOT escape providing an `alist`.  The `environment`--the box that assigns `values` to `variables`--IS ITSELF an `alist`.  The question is HOW the `alist` is inferred and specified.  It is you who has to specify the  ENVIRONMENT in which the mathematical expression is evaluated.  Lisp Evalutor will throw up if it cannot find a value for a variable it wants to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. It looks like it is impossible to do what I was trying unless there is some equivalent to "globals()" in Python for elisp. That is the environment I want to eval in. It isn't possible to anticipate what the alist would be in advance here, and if you have to make one you might as well just use it for the s-format arg anyway.

Comment: Which begs the question,  what is the source of the data ... My gut feeling is that you have some babel snippet in your org file (possibly using Python) which gets dumped in the Org file, which you want to use somewhere else.  You need to talk about more about source of data ... and not how data is used.

Comment: its not that complicated; it is all in code. The data here comes from an api and is json like https://api.openalex.org/works/W4210300109. I want to use that data to make a string representation. it isn't a simple use values from the json though, or I wouldn't have this question. I need a function to get an author string for example, and one to generate the abstract.  So in the template I want something like ${(get-abstract result)}.

Comment: curl https://api.openalex.org/works/W4210300109 |  jq '.authorships | .[].author.display_name'    => "Shanna-Leigh Davidson"
"Tagbo H. R. Niepa"  You just need to use `request-*` and `shell-command-*` and you are done.  There is a reason your `replacer` function is complicated, and but I have hard time imagining what is specific in scenario which makes the `replacer` look like that.

Comment: it is just because I wanted a simpler syntax than you describe. One for using functions to generate expansions, one like the path syntax in jq, and then the regular lookup, to avoid making verbose alists.  that is the solution (verbose alists) I have reverted to, its just longer and more tedious to write.